# How to use cassia to Create Remote Session and send input?

Tags: c#, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-services-gateway, cassia

I know I can use Remote Desktop ActiveX control, but I am trying to implement solution browser based solution just like browserstack.com etc, they have implemented same by using Flash which connects to their server which in turn might be rdp gateway.

I have looked at library Cassia, https://code.google.com/p/cassia/source/browse/trunk/Samples/SessionInfo/Source/SessionInfo/Program.cs, but I am not able to understand how to actually grab the screen and send input after we call `WTSStartRemoteControlSession` method.

I want to call these methods from an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, which basically stores scripts for automated UI testing. Most of the time, no body will be keeping any UI open, our test server will automatically create RDP session, run everything and then email results.

Only for recording tests, programmers will use Web UI which will communicate with server purely through web sockets and download images of screen. Using ActiveX control is not possible as we use UI Automation to capture text/UI element information etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, Cassia and the WTS API won't help you much here, since they're more for administering servers than interacting with individual sessions.

You could try an HTML5 RDP client like [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/). It has a JavaScript client API that allows you to send [key](http://guac-dev.org/doc/guacamole-common-js/symbols/Guacamole.Client.html#sendKeyEvent) and [mouse](http://guac-dev.org/doc/guacamole-common-js/symbols/Guacamole.Client.html#sendMouseState) events.

Comment: Thanks, but how does 2X has created its own events on server side. I need to do something on server side as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question -- what events is the 2X client creating? You can use [RDP virtual channels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383509(v=vs.85).aspx) to communicate with the server from the client.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, very comparable to Guacamole, you can try [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille), also open source and using [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) as rdp client through an HTTP gateway. The main difference is it's done in .NET (C#) and thus is more intended for Windows Servers.